# Android Studio Terminal Color is changing while using GIT. Unable to Read output

Tags: git, android-studio, terminal

I am using GIT in Android Studio Terminal.
When I type `git log` the background color changes and I am unable to read text.
Please see below output in Android Studio.

[image]

**However, when I run the same command in Normal Git.exe then the colors are showing properly.**
Please see image from only git.exe

[image]

I tried to change almost all settings in Android Studio, read all articles around this, but still could not find any solution.
Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Android Studio but git doing the coloring. There are a number of options to set the coloring of the git output. Like set no coloring for everything:

```
git config --global color.ui never
```

My experience with Android Studio is, however that not all color related settings work.
More info about git configuration from here:

```
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration
```